# When does ServiceConnection.onServiceDisconnected() get called?

Tags: android, android-service

I'm messing with Android services, and I have found that `ServiceConnection.onServiceConnected()` gets called fairly predictably when I bind to a service.

However, my `onServiceDisconnected()` method seems to never be called, even after the VM dies.

I have logged debug messages on the service and show that all threads have been shutdown, etc. I know services are implemented as processes; are there threads I don't know about that are preventing the process from exiting?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It happens upon remote service crash. So, if a service running in a different process than your client fails on some exception, you lose the connection and get the callback.

Comment: Is it just on crash? I would expect it to be called when I call `unbindService()` and the service exits because there are no more clients.

Comment: according to the documentation it only happens on 'unexpected service unbinding' , so yes, it's only on crash, and no on unbindService()

Comment: So, how can you know if you can actually rebind to the service ? Or better, how do you rebind ? Uing a new ServiceConnection ?

Comment: @Reflog That's true, although when you have bound the service using Context.BIND_NOT_FOREGROUND you are able to see the onDisconnectedService everytime you stop the service and unbind it. Checkout this [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13579965/how-to-force-the-onservicedisconnected-get-called)

Comment: You don't have to rebind; the connection remains even after the service has disconnected.  If the service revives, your onServiceConnected() method will be called again.

Comment: @Carl, Yeah, as you said, after disconnection, android is connecting again.

Comment: What gets called when the service is stopped?