# Stop bound sensor listener service

Tags: android, service, bindservice

I have a Service [a] that is logging sensor data.
This service is bound to the calling service [b]. However, i need to start the logger-service manually with `startService(intent)` bevor binding because i need th onCreate()-Method to run.

Is there a way to kill the Service [a] so that [b] is informed? (preferable from within the `onSensorChanged`-method of [a] and in a way that `onServiceDisconnected` is being called)

Answer (score 0):

According to the accepted answer of [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13579965/how-to-force-the-onservicedisconnected-get-called), it is actually very simple. After calling `startService()` just bind to the Service and put the `Context.BIND_NOT_FOREGROUND`-flag.

If you then call `stopSelf()` (after unregister the listener in my case) from within the bound service, the process is destroied and `onServiceDisconnected` will be called.
It might be not the best solution because `onServiceDisconnected` will also be called if some error kills the service... Better would be sending a broadcast. But it solved my problem.